# Java/SQLite - How to compile for -DTHREADSAFE=1?

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, sqlite

I made a MySQL pooler (So i can perform sql in Async threads) - but soon decided to add some other database options(Sqlite). Sadly plain Sqlite seems to not fully "support" multiple connections making the pooler completely useless. I continued to read up about Sqlite and noticed it actually has a few thread options, one being simple multithread.

My question is, how would i compile SQLite under -DTHREADSAFE=1? Or is it just suppose to be ran with that in the java arguments? I'm using Maven btw-

Also, i'm very open to different database options. For instance, does h2 support async? Thanks!

Comment: Does the world really need *another* connection pooler? Looking at the problems even the mature ones have, it seems it's really hard to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

SQLIte only provides thread safety, not additional performance when using multiple threads. You cannot have multiple threads access the same database at the same time, see http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html:

> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.

The performance will be even worse because it has to use mutexes to protect data structures, see http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6:

> However, the work of acquiring and releasing these mutexes will slow SQLite down slightly.